# Gradle: Copy one specific file from main project directory into subproject/build/libs

Tags: gradle, file-copying

Searching in vain for examples on this humble task, none worked, I need to learn how to use gradle to copy one specific file from the main directory of a gradle project (containing subprojects) and into the /build/libs folder of one of the subprojects. Structure is this:

```
mainProject folder
  file.txt
  Subproject folder
      build folder
          libs folder
            (I want to copy file.txt here)
```

This copy process shall be in the build.gradle (for the Subproject) file. I am using Android Studio and the subproject is a pure java application.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a custom task of type [`Copy`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html) to copy the file to the target directory. To access the file in the root project, you may use the [`rootProject`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:rootProject) property of the subproject.

```
task copyFileFromRootProject(type: Copy) {
    from "${rootProject.projectDir}/file.txt"
    into 'build/libs'
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have done approximately this solution in vain. Trying your particular code, the copytask still does not happen. Are there other pre-requisites that I need to define to make it work? For example, some write access flag or similar? Or must this task be in a particular position in the build.gradle file?

Comment: Apart from executing the task - either explicitly via `gradlew copyFileFromRootProject`, or as dependency to another default task - nothing else is required. Consider running the build with `--info --stacktrace --rerun-tasks` to get output suitable for debugging issues with the build setup.

Comment: for anyone looking into this. One option could be to use: `build.dependsOn(copyFileFromRootProject)`